# Jquery UI Autocomplete Shows Response for Earlier Text

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using Jquery autocomplete. If a user types 2 characters then waits, then types another. If the first response comes after the second, it will briefly show the second list then show the first list. How can I cancel the first request after a user starts typing more?

```
    $("#city").autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/geo/json_autocomplete.php",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    term: $("#city").val(),
                    countryid: $("#countryid").val()
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                        //console.debug(item.value+" "+item.label+" "+item.id);
                        return {
                            label: item.label,
                            value: item.value,
                            id: item.id
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        delay: 500,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            $("#cityid").val(ui.item.id);
            showForm();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Try adding in `async: false` as an option to the ajax request. I've found it helpful when I needed to maintain order in ajax requests. It may work for this too.

Comment: @Lester: This is not a good recommendation. Specifying `async: false` will lock up the browser for the duration of the request.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try storing the xhr in a variable and comparing it with the `xhr` parameter you get in the AJAX success callback. Only call the response function if the two match. You can also adjust the "delay" parameter accordingly.

```
var lastXhr;

$("#city").autocomplete({
    delay: 500, // 500ms between requests.
    source: function( request, response ) {
        lastXhr = $.ajax({
            url: "/geo/json_autocomplete.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                term: $("#city").val(),
                countryid: $("#countryid").val()
            },
            success: function( data, status, xhr ) { 
                if (xhr === lastXhr) {
                     response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                    //console.debug(item.value+" "+item.label+" "+item.id);
                        return {
                            label: item.label,
                            value: item.value,
                            id: item.id
                        };
                    }));
                }
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    delay: 500,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        $("#cityid").val(ui.item.id);
        showForm();
    }
});
```